# Redux/reselect selector function arguments explanation?

Tags: typescript, redux, memoization, reselect, memoized-selectors

I am working on a codebase written in Typescript that uses a lot of immutable reselect. I haven't been working with reselect yet and I have come across an example that I don't understand:

```
export const panelsSelector: (
  order: Order,
  events: List<List<Event>>,
  adminRole: boolean,
  packageEvents: List<List<PackageEvent>>,
) => List<PanelProps> = createImmutableEqualSelector(
  (order: Order) => order,
  (order: Order, events: List<List<Event>>) => events,
  (order: Order, events: List<List<Event>>, adminRole: boolean) => adminRole,
  (order: Order, events: List<List<Event>>, adminRole: boolean, packageEvents: List<List<PackageEvent>>) => packageEvents,
  (order, events, adminRole, packageEvents) => List<PanelProps>([
      {
        content: <Events packageEvents={packageEvents}
                         events={events}
                 />
      },
      {
        content: <MyComponent  packages={order.get('packages')}
                               adminRole={adminRole}
                               packagesCount={order.get('noOfPackages')}/>
      },
)
```

If I am reading this right `panelsSelector` is assigned I guess an anonymous type which is a function. In this case I guess `createImmutableEqualSelector` returns a function which returns `List<PanelProps>`. To simplify something like this:

```
const panelsSelector:(arg) => List<PanelProps> = createImmutableEqualSelector((arg) => List<PanelProps>)
```

What I don't understand in this example is why the selectors need to have an argument added from its predecessor to an argument list?

```
  (order: Order) => order,
  (order: Order, events: List<List<Event>>) => events,
  (order: Order, events: List<List<Event>>, adminRole: boolean) => adminRole,
  (order: Order, events: List<List<Event>>, adminRole: boolean, packageEvents: List<List<PackageEvent>>) => packageEvents
```

If I remove an argument from a predecessor for example for the second selector:

```
(events: List<List<Event>>) => events
```

I get a typescript error:

> Types of parameters 'state' and 'order' are incompatible.

So, why do this selectors need to be written like that?
So far I have only seen simple examples like this one where we get the data from the state:

```
const selectShopItems = state => state.shop.items
```

But, I don't understand the former example. If order is not state, then where is that data coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a Reselect selector, like `selectThing(state, 2, 3, 4)`, Reselect will then call each of the input selectors with each of those same inputs:

```js
const input1Result = inputSelector1(state, 2, 3, 4);
const input2Result = inputSelector2(state, 2, 3, 4);
const input3Result = inputSelector3(state, 2, 3, 4);
// etc
```

Reselect then passes each of those results to the final "output selector":

```js
const finalResult = outputFunction(input1Result, input2Result, input3Result);
```

So, *all* of the input functions will be called with the exact same arguments.

It's very common to have one or two input selectors that extract data from the Redux `state`, but also to extract some of the additional parameters as well:

```js
const selectItemId = (state, itemId) => itemId;
```

In this case, whoever wrote `panelsSelector` decided not to explicitly list all four parameters for all of the input selectors.  That's fine, because JS allows you to call a function with more parameters than it actually needs - they just need to all line up correctly (ie, all of them should expect `events` to be the second argument).

I do have a couple observations about this specific selector:

First, it shouldn't be necessary to explicitly specify the type of `panelsSelector`.  TS will know that it's a function that takes those arguments and returns that result.

Second, having a selector that returns JSX feels... kinda sketchy?  It'll work, but I personally would try to avoid that.  I'd want to return just a data structure, and keep the JSX part in the actual component.

Note that the latest version of Reselect (4.1.x) has much improved TS types as well.

And finally, [we recommend *against* using Immutable.js at all today with Redux](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-plain-javascript-objects-for-state), and especially given that our official Redux Toolkit package builds in use of Immer for immutable updates.

You may also want to read the Redux docs page on [Deriving Data With Selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors).

Comment: So whatever arguments that we want to get from the combiner function, they will all be passed to each of the selector functions in the exact same order. That was a great explanation! Thank you!

Comment: I know you are leaning more towards letting React virtual Dom compare sort out jsx comparing but this person in the React team is making a [compiler](https://youtu.be/lGEMwh32soc) to memoize things on a compile level because programmers either forget it or think it makes the code too complicated. For memoization and shorter code I usually curry multiple parameter selectors so my pure component has its own selector: `const item = useSelector(selectItemById(id))` and won't re render if selectItemById returns a new reference because each item component has its own selector.